# flask testing configuration in config.py vs. base test class

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I have a project where I defined a test configration in `config.py`, but I'm puzzled by the following:

1. Many times there is a testing configuration for `config.py`
   being discussed in tutorials, like [this one](https://github.com/damyanbogoev/flask-bookshelf/blob/master/bookshelf/config.py#L35-L39)
2. Actual testing with database is usually done on application and database
   defined in testclass (with or without Flask-Testing). This test setup does 
   not make use of testing configuration from `config.py`

   See for example Flask-SQLAlchemy [own test fixtures](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/tests/conftest.py)
   or some of links listed [here](https://github.com/mini-kep/db/issues/10#issuecomment-336132711)

There is some advice about a test database being created specifically for the tests, eg from [testing-with-sqlalchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/#testing-with-sqlalchemy):

> First, ensure you set the database URI to something other than your production database ! Second, it’s usually a good idea to create and drop your tables with each test run, to ensure clean tests

There are no tutorials that say **"you do not need a testing configuration, do your test setup in your base test class"**. Is this something assumed?

Tst configuration 
in `config.py` and explicit test setup in class - are they mutually exclusive?
Or sometimes you combine the two?

P.S. [Here](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html) is a list of project configurations without testing config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It is usually a matter of convenience. Prefer definitions in test module.

> Are a test configuration in config.py and explicit test setup in class mutually exclusive? Or sometimes you combine the two?

They are NOT mutually exclusive. You can put the config values

- in the `config.py` (or)
- in the test module (or)
- in both.

[Here](https://github.com/GluuFederation/cluster-mgr/blob/677fe7939898d1c32160569ade5b6848b0468dd7/tests/views/test_index.py) is an example using the `config.py` route for motivation.

---

The decision to store the test config is mostly project dependent.

The `config.py` with the class inheritance structure comes with its own set of rules. There are certain values like `SECRET_KEY` and Database connection strings which has to be changed at the deployment stage in order to ensure application security. So, in order to handle such a situation (especially in public open source projects) there is usually a file like `config.py.default` which carries all the default values. The developer/admin can copy this to config.py and add the values as per requirement. Using such a default config is recommended in [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#development-production).

In situations involving automated testing (eg., Continuous Integration), such a default config setup becomes unusable. So storing the test config in the modules provides a convenient solution.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. My takeaway is to use setup in test unless I need something reusable for purposes outside database testing.